# I cannot get Android ActionBar Custom theme to work (believe me I've tried)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, themes, android-appcompat

I'm sure I'll catch some grief for lack of specificity or asking a question that's been asked, but this truly is a last option and I've really tried too many ways to explain them all.  Here's my issue:

I've been going through the standard tutorials provided by developers.android.com and I've made it to the Styling of the ActionBar with pretty much no issues. Well now I'm paying for those lack of issues and I really cannot get any sort of custom theme to work on the action bar.

FACTS:

- I am using the AppCompat-V7 as my app will be quite simple and ideally compatible with as many versions as possible.
- I CAN change the basic themes (Dark, Light, and Light.DarkActionBar)
- I've attempted the Android Action Bar Style Generator and followed this turorial here (http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html)
- I've watched a handful of videos that somewhat related to my issue/settings to try and get it right.
- I've tried various methods (all wrong) to get this to work, some of which probably don't even make sense.

So... how about it?

Here are my files that I believe are relevant, but if anyone wants to see more, feel free to ask.  Considering I'm hardly through the Android tutorials, I don't have much to look at, so I suppose that's good.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="godwin.com.study" >


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="godwin.com.study.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "godwin.com.study"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0+"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Feel free to ask questions, but be prepared for "I have no idea".  I'm pretty much lost.  And yes, I did remove a lot of my attempts.  They overlapped and interfered with each other, so what I have here in my files does work, except for the line:

```
<item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

in the **themes.xml** file.  I have put my "actionbar_background.png" files into the "drawable" folder, but it still only produces the "...Light.DarkActionBar" theme.

I really hope it's something simple, but through all my searching I've yet to be able to find the answer.

ON A SIDE NOTE: This is my first time developing an Android App, or at least trying to, and I really don't think Android did a good job with their tutorials.  I mean, I'm decent at programming.  Been working with C++ mostly, but also some Java, Javascript, and web design languages, and I get them for the most part.  Is it just me? or is getting into the world of app development really dang difficult?

EDIT: To try and put it simply, I've tried many methods to change the looks of the actionbar with a custom theme (whether it's using color codes or images/.pngs), but the only way I can get it to change is by the use of the preset themes (Light, Dark, and Light.DarkActionBar).

Comment: "I really cannot get any sort of custom theme to work on the action bar" -- um, any chance that you could explain what you mean by this? Is it just the background? If yes, is there a reason you are not using the tint system (e.g., `colorPrimary`)?

Comment: I would like to be able to use something like the Android Action Bar Style Generator that I mentioned, so that would be a custom theme that changes the action bar (right?)  I also tried to use my own "actionbar_background".png as I stated and link to it (to see if I can change/customize any part of the action bar (progress is progress and I'd be happy temporarily being able to at least do that).  I did attempt to change the color to #ff0000 but I forgot what method I used.  Either way, it didn't work.  Ideally, I want to have control over the action bar, but I have yet to be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to be able to use something like the Android Action Bar Style Generator that I mentioned,

As is noted on the site, that generator is deprecated, because you do not need it with the AppCompat action bar. If your objective is to provide a custom background color to your action bar, and if you are on the current version of AppCompat (`appcompat-v7`, version 21 or higher), you do that via `colorPrimary`.

For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppCompat/ActionBarColor) sets a custom color on the action bar. It has a `res/values/colors.xml` that defines some colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="primary">#3f51b5</color>
  <color name="primary_dark">#1a237e</color>
  <color name="accent">#ffee58</color>
</resources>
```

It has a `res/values/styles.xml` that applies the `primary` color to the `colorPrimary` theme attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Apptheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

It applies the custom theme in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.commonsware.android.abverscolor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme">
        <activity
            android:name="ActionBarDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You get:

[image: AppCompat Action Bar, with Custom Theme, on Android 4.3]

Comment: I'm in the process of trying it out, so we'll see how it goes.  But on a side note, my version is not "21 or higher".  Its min = 8 and target = 18.  How will this affect the ability to change the actionbar?  Or, better yet, what would I need to do to make this work with the version compatibility I'm working toward?

Comment: I attempted to use that code and because I'm working toward lower versions, there's no resource found that matches any of the attributes "colorAccent, colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark".  Going to try and find a fix for that now.  Hopefully it leads to something.

Comment: @lilgodwin: "How will this affect the ability to change the actionbar?" -- AppCompat works back to API Level 7. "there's no resource found that matches any of the attributes "colorAccent, colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark" -- those come from `appcompat-v7`. If you are using Android Studio (or otherwise using Gradle for Android), the project is already set up to reference `appcompat-v7`. If you are using Eclipse or another IDE, you would need to attach the `appcompat-v7` Android library project to the app.

Comment: @lilgodwin: Note that the sample app ships with `minSdkVersion` of 14 in its manifest. That's mostly for some semblance of standardization in my book samples. If you modify that to be 7 instead, the app runs fine on an API Level 7 (Android 2.1) emulator.

Comment: @lilgodwin: Also note that your own project's `build.gradle` is *not* using the current AppCompat. If you are trying to use `colorPrimary` and kin, please change `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0+"` to `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0+"`.

Comment: Along with your actual answer, your comments have helped greatly.  It's now working.  Though, I had to change my min and target versions.  For this reason, I'm hoping I don't run into issues down the road with this, both during my development and for the users to will hopefully be using the app.  My app will be quite simple in nature, and I had hoped to make it as compatible with as many versions as possible.  Thanks so much for your help CommonsWare.

Comment: quick followup before I get further into my app, as I'm not sure if I've created an issue for myself.  Basically, as I see it, I initialized an app that was meant to be compatible with earlier versions, and I've been following the Android developers tutorial in regards to the "For Android 2.1 and higher" sections up until this point.  Since I've recently changed a bit of the code as you suggested (I now have the appcompat-v7 library along with a minSDK = 9 and targetSDK = 21 with appcompat support of 21+.  Would I likely run into any issues or is everything alright set this way?

Comment: @lilgodwin: That is a fairly typical setup for an app that will aim to support back to API Level 9 yet wishes to progressively enhance the experience on newer devices.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain things so well. If/when I get more reps, I'll be sure to upvote your answer.