# Cannot change color of actionbar with appcompact v7 and Android Studio 1.1 Preview

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I tried many styles to change color of actionbar but not worked.

This is my style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
 <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">#f01234</item>
</style>
```

My emulator version: Android 4.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28356073/115145

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `SupportV7` version 21 change `ActionBar` color use `colorPrimary` property

Like this:

```
<style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
    <!--<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>-->
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

In styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#eeeeee</item>
</style>
```

and in Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="yourPackage.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

i hope to help you.